# Python backend to Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, python, backbone.js

I am trying to develop a way for Python to build web applications. Using just one HTML file and a python file, the user should be able to develop a small web application. The connection between Python logic/events and HTML can be javascript, and wanted to use something that made life easier than passing a DOM object back and forth.

I found Backbone.js, and thought that this may be something to look into. Any ideas?
I was thinking that Python could create events in javascript structured by Backbone, and then the javascript could talk back and forth with server/client very easily.

Would this work? Or the use of a DOM object with all of the HTML id's and attributes is necessary to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how we create the webApp:

- At the client side, using HTML5+Javascript and backbonejs
- At the server side, using [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) and its REST plugin
- REST API is used between the client and the server

[Client/HTML5+Javascript + Backbone] ← REST → [Web-Server]—[Django/rest-plugin]

There are a few rest frameworks for Django.

- [django-rest-framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/)
- [tastypieapi](http://tastypieapi.org/)
- [django-piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home)

Alternative to Django

- [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)

Also you can see the post in [here as well.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221627/building-rest-apis-for-python/17224087#17224087)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for tip! I like that idea. Think I'm gonna start with a microframework though, like Flask.

Comment: Also what do you communicate in REST calls? Do you keep a DOM object that is being passed back and forth? That's really what I am struggling with, understanding what is needed to communicate back and forth between server and client.

Comment: In our work the client is wrapped as PhoneGap app and its codes (HTML & javascript) are inside the client, the rest calls, think of it as ajax calls for now (someone reads this statement will be screaming since they are not the same), passing the data between client and server. All the rendering and templating can be done @ the client using backbone and underscore-template. You can read the posting in here for rest url design: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201030/how-an-rpc-style-example-would-look-modelled-in-a-resource-centric-style/17240059#17240059